# iTunes COM interface

Tags: python, com, itunes

I would like to be able to control iTunes with python.

I know this is possible and I successfully tested some examples I have seen here at stackoverflow and in other sites, too.

However, I would like to read the documentation about this. I have registered in Mac Dev Center, and when try to access the [link] where the docs are, but I am redirected to the Mac Dev Center.

Has anyone been able to download the docs, or is it just me?

Thanks,
nunos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has moved things around and failed to update their sites appropriately (trying to download the itunes sdk directly does bounce you back as you've observed), but by faithfully following the instructions found [here](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/05/20/itunes-com-for-windows-sdk-now-in-adc.aspx) I've been able to download the zipfile with the SDK and it appears to be intact and usable.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-Scriptum: I use the COM for Windows, which is usable through Python.

I have been able to download (leagaly) both an ActivePython install ([here](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads)) and the documentation for it (although i can't seem to find the link anymore, I have the file; send me your email if you need it).

It is a very good tool, but you will unboutly need the documentation in order to get through.

Don't forget [google](http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=itunes%20com%20download#sclient=psy&hl=fr&source=hp&q=itunes%20windows%20com%20example&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=122b790cdd433dfe) if you need examples.

Hope I helped.